# How to use library function in view in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I created my own library file in :
app/lib/mylib.php
in mylib.php I have a function :

```
<?php
class Mylib {
    public function get_discount($item){
        $this->loadModel('ServiceCharge');
        $this->loadModel('ZeroServiceCharge');
        $service_crages=$this->ServiceCharge->find('all');
        $zero_service_charge=$this->ZeroServiceCharge->find('all');
        $zero_service_charge=$zero_service_charge[0]['ZeroServiceCharge']['items'];
        if( $item>=$zero_service_charge){
            return 100;
        }
        foreach ($service_crages as $service_crage) {
            pr($service_crage);
            exit;
   //if($service_crage)
        }


    }
}
?>
```

Then I add the following line app/controller/AppController.php:

```
App::uses('Mylib', 'Lib');
```

and finally I call this function in nocontact.ctp :

```
 echo get_discount( $total_pieces);
```

But it shows the following error:

```
Error: Call to undefined function get_discount()
```

Whats wrong am I doing?

Comment: Which version of Cake are you using?

Answer (score -1):

```
App::uses('Lib', 'Mylib');
class yourController extends AppController{

  public function viewPage(){


   $this->set('variableToView', $this->get_discount($param));

}

}
```

View:

```
echo $variableToView
```